# Create Field using fluentd

Tags: elasticsearch, fluentd

I have logs that I am consuming with Fluentd and sending to Elasticsearch. I would like to create a new field if a string is found.

Sample log:

```json
{
  "@timestamp": "2021-01-29T08:05:38.613Z",
  "@version": "1",
  "message": "Started Application in 110.374 seconds (JVM running for 113.187)",
  "level": "INFO"
}
```

I would like to create a new field **STARTIME** and the value, in this case, would be **113.187**

What I have tried is, used the record_transformer and ruby split to get the value but it seems when it matches it remove the string I want from the log file.

```xml
<filter**>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby true
  <record>
    STARTIME ${record["message"].split("JVM running").last.split(")")}
  </record>
</filter>
```

How can I create this new field with the desired value?

I have now used the suggested option below:

```
<filter**>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby true
  <record>
    STARTIME ${record["message"].split("JVM running for ").last.split(")")[0]}
  </record>
</filter>
```

Which got me closer. What's happening now is the Field STARTIME is created and when the log entry matches it has the value of **113.187** which is correct however every other line that does not match this pattern just gets added to the new field.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "it seems when it matches it remove the string I want from the log file"? Can you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: Just tested your sample log with this: `STARTIME ${record["message"].split("JVM running for ").last.split(")")[0]}` and the output via stdout is `2021-01-30 18:45:05.885183400 +0500 test: {"@timestamp":"2021-01-29T08:05:38.613Z","@version":"1","message":"Started Application in 110.374 seconds (JVM running for 113.187)","level":"INFO","STARTIME":"113.187"}`.

Comment: @Azeem , thanks that has got me closer. What's happening now is the Field STARTIME is created and when the log entry matchs it give the 113.187 which is correct however every other line that does not match this pattern just gets added to the new field.

Comment: Can you please update your question with an example?

Comment: Can you afford to have `STARTIME` with `null` if the actual value is not found?

Comment: Try: `STARTIME ${ s = record['message'][/JVM running for \d{3}.\d{3}/]; s ? s.split(' ')[-1] : nil }`

Comment: The `STARTIME` field will have a valid value, `null` otherwise. So, handle accordingly on the other side.

Comment: You're welcome! I'll post an answer shortly with a description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<record>
  STARTIME ${ s = record['message'][/JVM running for \d{3}.\d{3}/]; s ? s.split(' ')[-1] : nil }
</record>
```

`STARTIME` will have the valid value, `null` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not a direct answer to solve this using Fluentd transformations, but you could use Elasticsearch [ingestion pipelines](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/ingest.html) together with [grok processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/grok-processor.html) to extract your data. This is a simulated example:

```json
POST _ingest/pipeline/_simulate
{
  "pipeline": {
    "description": "Enrich logs",
    "processors": [
      {
        "grok": {
          "field": "message",
          "patterns": [
            "(JVM running for %{NUMBER:start_time})"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "docs": [
    {
      "_source": {
        "@timestamp": "2021-01-29T08:05:38.613Z",
        "@version": "1",
        "message": "Started Application in 110.374 seconds (JVM running for 113.187)",
        "level": "INFO"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

`_source` is the document you have provided and there's a single grok processor to extract `start_time` from the `message` field. Calling this pipeline results in:

```json
{
  "docs" : [
    {
      "doc" : {
        "_index" : "_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "_id",
        "_source" : {
          "start_time" : "113.187",
          "@timestamp" : "2021-01-29T08:05:38.613Z",
          "level" : "INFO",
          "@version" : "1",
          "message" : "Started Application in 110.374 seconds (JVM running for 113.187)"
        },
        "_ingest" : {
          "timestamp" : "2021-01-29T14:09:43.447147676Z"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You can see that after transformation, your document contains `"start_time" : "113.187"` value.